# How to tell if a script is being executed from a plugin, a theme or a child theme in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, themes, child-theme, paths, plugins-url

I have a framework for WordPress that can be embedded into either a **plugin**, a **theme** or a **child theme**. In order to return proper URLs, the script needs to determine from where it is being executed.

I believe I could do something like matching `__FILE__` against:

- `get_template_directory_uri()` (theme),
- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` (theme or child theme), or
- `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` (plugin)

Is there a better, more reliable approach than using [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/strpos) to compare the above? How would I go about it?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have edited my question. I'm looking for a reliable, non-arbitrary method to determine where the current file is located in the WordPress hierarchy. Optimally, we could make a function called `where_am_i()` that would return either "theme", "child-theme" or "plugin".

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have edited my question. I'm looking for a reliable, non-arbitrary method to determine where the current file is located in the WordPress hierarchy.